# How can I complete Law and Order without starting a new game?

Tags: dragon-age-origins-awakening

I would like to resume an old Awakening save, but on loading I discovered that I must have triggered the Smuggler's Run/Law and Order interaction ["bug"](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Law_and_Order).

The bartender's *"open the passage"* dialogue was activated after both Law and Order and Smuggler's Run quests were active, resulting in the player being able to kill the smuggler leader but Aidan and the guards think I murdered the Lieutenant.

I don't want start a new game. **Is there any otherway to get around this so that I can complete the Law and Order quest?** (e.g. by using the console?)

1. `runscript zz_coa_debug` does not provide any useful options.
2. `runscript zz_getsetplotflag set coa000pt_smugglers 21 0` does not appear to help, even after a reload or leaving Amaranthine and returning (this requires zz_getsetplotflag.ncs in `packages/core/override`). Flag 21 appears (by inspecting the Awakening `designerplots.erf` to be the flag set when you kill the Lieutenant.
3. Aidan's current dialogue, *"I've nothing to say to you."*, does not appear to have a `CONVERSATION_LINE_COND PLOT` triggering on a particular flag so perhaps some additional processing has caused the current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more exploring and I wouldn't have needed to ask. Oops.

Both Smuggler's Run and Law and Order have a plot flag that declares the chain locked. This needs to be unset to continue Law and Order.

Use `zz_getsetplotflag` to unset the flag that locks the Law and Order chain:

```
runscript zz_getsetplotflag set coa000pt_city_guard 8 0
```

You should now be able to talk to Aidan for your reward. Now, this assumes the player has already killed the smuggler leader, as I had. If you haven't, you may need to use an editor like the GFF editor to have a look and identify any other flags you may need to change.

Note that *this does not update your journal quest entries* but does get you the reward for the quest and updates the way Aidan and the other guards treat you. If I find a way to update the quest entries I will update this answer.

---

I also recommend unsetting at least flag 19 of Smuggler's Run (this is the flag set by the bartender conversation about the passage) in case it has the potential to cause any future issues.

```
runscript zz_getsetplotflag set coa000pt_smugglers 19 0
```

The valid Smuggler's Run flags are 0 through 24 as well 256 and 257.